# Custom whitelisting domain names - Python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, whitelist, domain-name

In my project, I want to whitelist a set of domains to handle requests. It should allow all requests from the listed domain, its sub-domains and different pages on the domain.

So, if, for example, one of the whitelisted domains is `example.com`, it should serve requests for `www.example.com`, `abc.example.com`, `https://abc.def.example.com`, `example.com/pg1` etc.

Which is the best utility/ library that can be used for this purpose? Or, do I need to write my own regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match subdomains of the domain `example.com`.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*example\.com\/?.*
```

Comment: This also matches `.example.com`. :|

Comment: Fixed it now, so it won't match `.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this python function to check if a url should be allowed based on your domain:

```
def isDomainAllowed(url)
  domain = 'example.com'
  match = re.search(r'example.com', url)
  if match and match.group() == domain:
    return True
  return False
```

Comment: In this case, it will also match `kexample.com`, which is a complete different url.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use python lib [tldextract](https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/).

Simple validation:

```
import tldextract

def validate_whitelist_url(url: str) -> bool:
    whitelist_hosts = ["domain.com", "gmail.com"]
    extracted_hosts = (tldextract.extract(host) for host in whitelist_hosts)

    _url = tldextract.extract(url)

    for host in extracted_hosts:
        if _url.subdomain == host.subdomain and _url.domain == host.domain and _url.suffix == host.suffix:
            return True
    return False
```

You can customize validation like you want, because you have separated data about domain, suffix, subdomain